# Refactoring method output PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

If I have:

```
def method():
    return output1
```

And I change to:

```
def method():
    return output1, output2
```

Can I do automatically do this refactoring throughout the codebase in Pycharm?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you expect as a result of this refactoring... If it is to have change `output1 = method()` to `output1, output2 = method()` then I don't think PyCharm will do that for you. It doesn't make sense to me...